# HTTPBuilder encoding utf-8 in Grails

Tags: grails, utf-8

I have a problem using HTTPBuilder in Grails.

The code is something like this.

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder("theURL")

http.request(method, ContentType.JSON) {
    uri.path = "theURI"

    headers.'Authorization' = "OAuth  $accessToken"
    headers.'Accept' = "application/json"
    headers.'content-type' = "application/json;charset=utf-8"

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        result = json
    }
}

return result
```

Now the response is a JSON with "Cobro N�� 1234" but i need "Cobro Nº 1234"

I tried this with curl and the response is fine "Cobro Nº 1234", this made me think that the problem is the HTTPBuilder and not my API who response the request.

I think that it is a problem with the response encoding.

Comment: The endpoint you're hitting is public?

Comment: Is an API in salesforce with authentication (but i delete this part of code in the snippet)

Comment: Have you tried setting `content-type` as `application/json;charset=utf-8` ?

Comment: I tried but the problem continues "Cobro N�� 1234"

Comment: `Accept-Charset` should also have to be set to `UTF-8` in header.

Comment: What headers do you receive with incoming response?

Comment: "Accept-Charset: UTF-8" did not work :(

Comment: I received the next headers

- Date : Thu, 16 Apr 2015 16:35:47 GMT -
- Content-Type : application/json -
- Content-Encoding : gzip -
- Transfer-Encoding : chunked -

Comment: Thanks you all, the problem is inside the company server network

Answer (score 1):

```
http.encoders.charset = Charsets.UTF_8
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
headers.'content-type' = "application/JSON;charset=UTF-8" //capitalized
```

Either, try this:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after your 'http' declaration:

```
http.encoderRegistry = new EncoderRegistry( charset: 'utf-8' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow if the content you are sending needs to be encoded with UTF-8, or if the content you are receiving needs to be read with UTF-8.

I was having a problem sending content with UTF-8, and this is what I did.

```
http.request(Method.PUT) { request ->
    // set headers here
    request.entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8")
}
```

I'm converting a `net.sf.json.JSONObject` to a `String` in order to pass it along as the body of the `PUT` call. I'm using `StringEntity`, and previously I wasn't setting the encoding on the `StringEntity`, but there is a constructor that takes an encoding. Now that I'm setting "UTF-8" there, it is working.